# NODE.JS How do I save JSON data without filling up my storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

The title really explains it.

I made a discord bot, and I added a ranking system that had its memory in my filesystem. However, if too many people join, my storage would just get filled up. Perhaps there is a way for me to access the node.js server? Maybe localhost? I just want anything that saves data *for free*, *is not managed by anyone other than me*, and *doesn't take up my storage*.

Comment: Could you expand a little bit on what you're doing and give a little bit more context to your question? Currently, the question sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Perhaps you're looking for a [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database).

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Comment: @cbr yes! I want a database. Do you have any way I can get one?

Comment: @BraveButter can you tell me how I can make it clearer?

Comment: There's many free services depending on what kind of a database you're looking for. There's MongoDB, which is a document database and hence a bit closer to "saving JSON data". MongoDB, the company, provides [a free starting tier](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) for a _hosted_ MongoDB. For other databases, e.g. PostgreSQL and MySQL and others, there's lots of services out there that provide a free starting tier. You'll want to search for "managed [database name here]" or "hosted".

Comment: To make it better, elaborate a bit on what you've already tried, with code if possible. Tell what your project is doing - what you're trying to do with it. That'll give a clearer picture of just what you're ultimately mean by saying "saving JSON data".

Comment: @cbr I do not really trust those free services. Perhaps there is a way for me to access the Node.js server itself?

Comment: @cbr well I tried some things already but I already deleted the code. It wasn't quick, or clear anyways what I tried

Comment: There really isn't much more I can tell you without additional details about exactly what you're trying to do. Please [edit[(https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67586830/edit) your question to include details about what your project is about.

Comment: What do you mean with "my storage"? Where are you running your bot? Also, you want something for free but you also don't trust free services?

Comment: See, I want it for free, but not something managed by other people. @AKX

Comment: That still doesn't answer the first question. What storage are you talking about?

Comment: My PC's storage

Comment: So just run any DB on your local machine)

Comment: What is a DB?  How do I use this?
Edit: Oh you just shortened database lol

Comment: Well, if the constraints are that it can't be managed by other people (i.e. it can't be somewhere on the internet) and it has to be free, then you'll probably have to look around marketplaces for a free external hard drive you can plug in to your PC, and have your bot store stuff there.

Comment: @NikitaMazur Any database running on OP's machine would also use up their precious, limited storage.

Comment: @AKX, but he wants to use PC storage) or?)

Comment: @MrMythical DB = Database

Comment: I realized I have a drive with 399GB of storage left! I can use that can't I? Each object in the JSON file only has 2 properties:
"rank": xx
"xp": xxxxx
And that would take many users to get to 399 GB

Comment: @MrMythical Yes, you'd just have your bot write to a file on that drive instead (or set up a database that uses that drive as storage). A quick test implies that 10 000 users would take up with your schema would take up about 700 kilobytes of disk space, i.e. about 70 bytes per user. With 399 GB, you could store about 5 700 000 000 users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**config**

For this answer we'll establish a simple `config` object to store any values -

```js
// config.json

{"counter":0}
```

**server**

We will create a simple server using [http.createServer](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener). We will use the request method and request URL to look up a `handler` or respond with 404 when no handler is found -

```js
// server.js

import { createServer } from "http"
import { readFile, writeFile } from "fs/promises"

const server = createServer(async (req, res) => {
  const handler = routes?.[req.method.toLowerCase()]?.[req.url]
  if (handler == null) {
    res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
    res.end(`No route for ${req.method} ${req.url}`)
  }
  else {
    await handler(req, res)
    res.end()
  }
})

server.listen(8000)
```

Next we define the `routes` to `/getConfig` and `/saveConfig` -

```js
// server.js (continued)

const routes = {
  get: {
    "/getConfig": async (req, res) => {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'application/json'})
      res.write(await readFile("./config.json"))
    }
  },
  post: {
    "/saveConfig": async (req, res) => {
      await writeFile("./config.json", await readBody(req))
      res.writeHead(204)
    },
    "/reset": async (req, res) => {
      await writeFile("./config.json", JSON.stringify({ counter: 0 }))
      res.writeHead(204)
    }
  }
}
```

This depends on a reusable helper, `readBody` -

```js
// server.js (continued)

function readBody(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const body = []
    req.on('data', chunk => body.push(Buffer.from(chunk)))
    req.on('end', _ => resolve(Buffer.concat(body).toString()))
    req.on('error', reject)
  })
}
```

**client**

In this case your bot is the http client. The node docs for [http.get](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback) include this long-winded example, but don't let it worry you -

```js
// example from node docs

http.get('http://localhost:8000/', (res) => {
  const { statusCode } = res;
  const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

  let error;
  // Any 2xx status code signals a successful response but
  // here we're only checking for 200.
  if (statusCode !== 200) {
    error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                      `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
  } else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
    error = new Error('Invalid content-type.\n' +
                      `Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`);
  }
  if (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    // Consume response data to free up memory
    res.resume();
    return;
  }

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  let rawData = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
  res.on('end', () => {
    try {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
      console.log(parsedData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});
```

You're not expected to copy this verbatim. Imagine writing that much code each time you wanted to fetch some JSON. You can think of the [http](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html) module as a low-level API that enables you to design higher-level functions -

```js
// client.js 

import * as http from "http"

function request (href, { body = "", ...options } = {}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    http.request(href, options, res => {
      const data = []
      res.on('data', chunk => data.push(chunk))
      res.on('end', _ => resolve({
        status: res.statusCode,
        headers: res.headers,
        data: Buffer.concat(data).toString()
      }))
    })
    .on('error', reject)
    .end(body)
  )
}
```

Above our `request` function resolves a `{ status, headers, data }` object, and we can write specialized forms `get` and `getJson` that make it even easier to intereact with -

```js
// client.js (continued)

async function get (href) {
  const { status, headers, data } = await request(href)
  if (status < 200 || status >= 300)
    throw Error(status)
  return { status, headers, data }
}

async function getJson (href) {
  const { headers, data } = await get(href)
  if (!headers['content-type'].startsWith("application/json"))
    throw Error(`expected application/json but received ${headers['content-type']}`)
  return JSON.parse(data)
}
```

We can do the same for `post` -

```js
// client.js (continued)

async function post (href, body = "") {
  const { status, headers, data } = await request(href, { body, method: "POST" })
  if (status < 200 || status >= 300)
    throw Error(status)
  return { status, headers, data }
}
```

Finally here is our `bot` code. It reads the config via `get`, updates the config via `post`, and re-reads it via `get` to return the confirmed result -

```js
// client.js (continued)

async function bot() {
  const config = await getJson("http://localhost:8000/getConfig")
  await post("http://localhost:8000/saveConfig", JSON.stringify({counter: config.counter + 1}))
  return getJson("http://localhost:8000/getConfig")
}

bot().then(console.log, console.error)
```

**run**

Start the `server` in your terminal -

```sh
$ node ./server.js
```

In a **separate terminal**, run the `client` a few times -

```sh
$ node ./client.js
```

```js
{ counter: 1 }
```

```sh
$ node ./client.js
```

```js
{ counter: 2 }
```

```sh
$ node ./client.js
```

```js
{ counter: 3 }
```

**node modules**

Above we took a sort of DIY approach to the problem. But this kind of problem has been solved many ways before. There are popular libraries like [express](http://expressjs.com) and [koajs](https://koajs.com) that would make much of this a lot easier. Now that you know the purpose they serve, give 'em a try!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a database, [mongoDB atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) will work well in your case because it is cloud based and very easy to set up. You can follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyWdNBbzTIA&ab_channel=WornOffKeys) to connect your discord bot with mongoDB atlas.